# Rest Full API PHP - GET Postback Events

Tags: php, rest, api, response, postback

I have a problem with REST FULL PHP API.
Data sent to the server - everything OK.
However, I have a problem with data sent by the server, received.

API documentation is on Google Drive - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DtL5U8ardnt7twGKrQxROZAUYNiHxogE/view?usp=sharing

Page 5 "Application Progress Events".

I am trying to save the transmitted data from the site via PHP:

```
<?php 
$get = json_encode($_GET, true);
$post = json_encode($_POST, true);
$request = json_encode($_REQUEST, true);
$headers = json_encode(getallheaders(), true);
$server = json_encode($_SERVER, true);

$data = 
"===============================
        \n\r". $get 
. "\n\r\n\r" . $post
. "\n\r\n\r" . $headers
. "\n\r\n\r" . $server
. "\n\r\n\r" . $request
. "\n\r===============================";

$dane = $data . "\n\r\n\r"; 

// only for test...
$file = "database.txt"; 
$fp = fopen($file, "a"); 
flock($fp, 2); 
fwrite($fp, $dane); 
flock($fp, 3); 
fclose($fp); 
?>
```

However, only data is saved in the file:

```
===============================


{"evt":"progress"}


[]


{"Connection":"Keep-Alive","Accept":"application\/json, application\/xml, text\/json, text\/x-json, text\/javascript, text\/xml","Request-Context":"appId=cid-v1:5374fb20-adb0-496a-8742-7237cbd59270","x-ms-request-root-id":"58a47a3-4d205f11cc354ae9","x-ms-request-id":"|58a47a3-4d205f11cc354ae9.1.93e8a739_1.","Request-Id":"|58a47a3-4d205f11cc354ae9.1.93e8a739_1.","Host":"sv.pl"}


{"PATH":"\/usr\/local\/bin:\/usr\/bin:\/bin","LD_PRELOAD":"\/usr\/local\/lib\/h88\/av.so","HTTP_ACCEPT":"application\/json, application\/xml, text\/json, text\/x-json, text\/javascript, text\/xml","HTTP_CONNECTION":"Keep-Alive","HTTP_HOST":"sv.pl","HTTP_REQUEST_CONTEXT":"appId=cid-v1:5374fb20-adb0-496a-8742-7237cbd59270","HTTP_X_MS_REQUEST_ROOT_ID":"58a47a3-4d205f11cc354ae9","HTTP_X_MS_REQUEST_ID":"|58a47a3-4d205f11cc354ae9.1.93e8a739_1.","HTTP_REQUEST_ID":"|58a47a3-4d205f11cc354ae9.1.93e8a739_1.","DOCUMENT_ROOT":"\/home\/salvusmone\/domains\/sv.pl\/private_html","REMOTE_ADDR":"52.174.36.1","REMOTE_PORT":"33464","SERVER_ADDR":"185.208.164.122","SERVER_NAME":"sv.pl","SERVER_ADMIN":"webmaster@sv.pl","SERVER_PORT":"443","REQUEST_URI":"\/app\/test.php?evt=progress","HTTPS":"on","SSL_PROTOCOL":"TLSv1.2","SSL_SESSION_ID":"55139282ad60fee254cf0dc3b288283ef948882eaeb40854776fbab25a26d690","SSL_CIPHER":"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256","SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE":"128","SSL_CIPHER_ALGKEYSIZE":"128","SCRIPT_FILENAME":"\/home\/salvusmone\/domains\/sv.pl\/private_html\/app\/test.php","QUERY_STRING":"evt=progress","SCRIPT_URI":"https:\/\/sv.pl\/app\/test.php","SCRIPT_URL":"\/app\/test.php","SCRIPT_NAME":"\/app\/test.php","SERVER_PROTOCOL":"HTTP\/1.1","SERVER_SOFTWARE":"LiteSpeed","REQUEST_METHOD":"GET","PHP_SELF":"\/app\/test.php","REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT":1531835121.5215,"REQUEST_TIME":1531835121}


{"evt":"progress"}

===============================
```

The evt = progress variable results from the URL API configuration:
https://qsnapnet.com/snaps/ucqynntgts8oxbt

I have no ideas what to do ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved the problem:

```
$datas = json_encode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$datasX = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);


echo $datasX['rapida_id'];
echo $datas;
```